# What is the standard location for libjvm.so and libjvm.dylib in Java 9

Tags: java-native-interface, java-9

I am trying to figure out the *standardized* location of the files to pass to the linker when embedding Java 9 with my (C) program. I.e. the "correct" paths to `libjvm.so` (Linux/Solaris) and `libjvm.dylib` (macOS). This is so that my build-scripts and the like can be future safe.

Java 9 changed the layout of a Java installation ([JEP 220](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/220)), in order to make the file layout standardized, but all documentation I have seen are *not* correctly describing the location of the `libjvm` shared libraries in the Oracle and OpenJDK releases of Java 9 on Linux and macOS.

So, is there updated authoritative documentation anywhere?

[JEP 220](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/220) (which claims to be "Delivered", as part of [JSR 376: JavaTM Platform Module System](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr376/index.html), which is part of Java 9) says:

> The lib directory on Linux, macOS, and Solaris contains the run-time system's dynamically-linked native libraries, as it does today. These files, named libjvm.so or libjvm.dylib, may be linked against by programs that embed the run-time system.

(Similar descriptions are repeated in several related bug-tracker issues, and on the web.)

But that description does not describe the current (final) releases. Instead, they all seem to put the dynamic libraries in `lib/server/`, not in `lib/`.

(OpenJDK, at least on Ubuntu, has additional deviations from the layout described in [JEP 220](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/220).)

Note that I am only interested in linking with the full JDK installations, e.g. as obtained from Oracle or OpenJDK. I will not build my own installation and I will not distribute a copy of the java runtime libraries with my applications.

Comment: I could see a similar location for the library in Java8 as well as Java9 - `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/server/libjvm.dylib` and 
`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib` on MacOSX.

Comment: The question is not clear. The only change in JDK 9 is that on Linux and Solaris, libjvm.so is that the $ARCH directory is removed so it's now in lib rather than lib/$ARCH. Is the question about the VM type directory (under lib)? It would also be useful to understand what "OpenJDK has additional deviations from the layout describe in JEP 220" means as they should be aligned.

Comment: Additional deviations: The OpenJDK installation (Ubuntu 17.04) has no `conf/` directory in `/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/`.

Comment: @AlanBateman I do not see what is unclear. JEP 220, as quoted above, says that `libjvm.so` is in `lib/`, but that is not where `libjvm.so` is located after installing Java 9 on Linux (or macOS) with the installers from Oracle or using apt-get to install OpenJDK.

Comment: If you have a Linux install then you should find it in lib/server/libjvm.so, the $ARCH directory no longer exist. It hasn't changed on macOS, you should find lib/server/libjvm.dylib as before. Is your point that JEP 220 doesn't mention the VM variant sub-direcory?

Comment: OpenJDK builds have the top-level "conf" directory. I can't say what Ubuntu is doing but would be very strange if they are moving user editable configuration to another location.

Comment: @AlanBateman Yes, my point is that JEP 220 clearly states that, in the restructured "New run-time image structure", there should be a `lib/libjvm.so`, but there is not, in the "usual" installs. So I wondered whether this was changed and if the current behavior is documented in a standardized/future-proof way.